# Trying to dispatch an action from the fabric.js event handler causes "Reducers may not dispatch actions."

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, fabricjs, react-redux

I am developing an app using fabric.js and redux/react.

Shortly, what I want is when I add an object on the canvas it got selected and written into the app state.

And here is what I have for now - when I click on an object on the canvas the "object:selected" event
is fired and I dispatch the action to save the selected object into the state of my app.

```
fabricCanvas.on('object:selected', function(options) {
    store.dispatch({ 
       type: 'SET_SELECTED_OBJECT',
       object: options.target 
    })
})
```

It works pretty well, but the fun starts when I try to automatically set object as selected when it's added to the canvas.

```
fabricCanvas.on('object:added', function(options) {
   fabricCanvas.setActiveObject(options.target) 
})
```

The function setActiveObject() fires the "object:selected" which is pretty logical and I expected my handler with dispatch to work but instead it grants me with

```
Uncaught Error: Reducers may not dispatch actions.
```

I know that there is a restriction to dispatch actions from reducers but I can't get why Redux thinks that I try to.

From the event handler I trigger another event which dispatch an action. 
What I am doing wrong?

UPDATED:
Both handlers are defined in index.js right after the store and fabric defined.

```
import 'babel-polyfill';
import React from 'react'
import { render } from 'react-dom'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import { createStore } from 'redux'
import rootReducer from './reducers'
import App from './components/App'

import { clearSelectedObject, setSelectedObject, addObject } from './actions'
import initialState from './initialState.js'



let store = createStore(rootReducer, initialState, window.devToolsExtension && window.devToolsExtension())


render(
    <div id="ocdc-holder">
        <Provider store={store}>
            <App />
        </Provider> 
    </div>,
    document.getElementById('root')
)

const fabricCanvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas-lower')

fabricCanvas.on('object:added', function(options) {
   fabricCanvas.setActiveObject(options.target) 
})

fabricCanvas.on('object:selected', function(options) {
    store.dispatch({ 
       type: 'SET_SELECTED_OBJECT',
       object: options.target 
    })
})
```

Here is my reducers.js file http://pastebin.com/SFHZ9jVr

Comment: Where you are defining these two event handlers?

Comment: Also, could you provide all reducers code on pastebin.com?

Comment: Updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your handling `ADD_TEXT` action `reducers.js` file:

```
const newTextObj = new fabric.Text(action.payload.text)
fabricCanvas.add(newTextObj)
fabricCanvas.fire('object:selected')
return {
    ...state,
    objects: [
        ...state.objects,
        newTextObj
    ]
}
```

You shouldn't fire any events in reducers.

Fire them before/after dispatching `ADD_TEXT` action:

```
// Somewhere in component, or where you are dispatching `ADD_TEXT` action.
const newTextObj = new fabric.Text(action.payload.text)
fabricCanvas.add(newTextObj)
fabricCanvas.fire('object:selected')
```

Reducers should be free from side-effects. Everything reducer should do, is to return new state, using previous state and dispatched action.

You are getting this error, because you are firing `'object:selected'` event in reducer, which produces action dispatching.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I copied the wrong version of reducers.js.
Actually there is no this line firing event. 
http://pastebin.com/isTqYRhF

Comment: @MaxHladkiy, but you still creating `newTextObj` and adding it to canvas there. This code also should be removed from reducer.

Comment: So the error is caused by setActiveObject() function which itself fires the 'objects:selected' event. And I can't understand why(

Comment: Anyway, reducers are not the place for instantiating objects. Try to remove all code, which performs side-effects, from reducers.

Comment: I mean, that everything reducers should do, is to return new state, and nothing more.

Comment: Ok, I moved the object adding into the react component handler
http://pastebin.com/U34hVQEd
so now my reducer only returns new state.
And it works, great! Thank you!
But now I am struggling upon the question where should I dispatch my actions from - react component or fabric event handlers?

Comment: True way - is to move handling fabric events code to root component's `componentDidMount` function. But in your case, I think it would be very cumbersome. If you haven't any problems with current approach, you can leave it as is.